# Технология связки в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Разбирался с *binding* в WPF и столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть класс "Sensor", окно, в котором расположен только "DataGrid".

[image: Как выглядит работающая программа]

У "DataGrid" есть 3 столбца: "название элемента", "состояние датчика", "значение датчика", которые соответственно связаны со свойствами `Name`, `Condition`, `Value` и в добавок свойство второго выпадающего списка `IsEnabled` связано со свойством `IsActived` у класса "Sensor". Проблема в том, что при изменении свойств элементов в списке, не меняются свойства, которые я связал. То есть мне приходится сбрасывать `SourceItems` в `null` и потом снова присваивать ему мой список `source` (можно найти в методе ComboBox_SelectionChanged в коде "MainWindow.xaml.cs"). По логике, если я выбираю в первом выпадающем списке "Выключен", то свойство `Sensor.IsActivated` становится равным `false` и следовательно, связанное с ним свойство второго выпадающего списка `Combobox.IsEnabled` должно также равняться `false`, однако я по прежнему могу взаимодействовать с этим элементом управления. Пожалуйста помогите решить данную проблему.

Простой класс Sensor здесь:

```
public sealed class Sensor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte Condition { get; set; }

    public byte Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsActivated => Condition == 0

    public Sensor(string name, byte condition, byte value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Condition = condition;
    }
}
```

Дизайн окна и сами связки здесь:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="450"
    Width="800">

<!--Сама таблица-->
<DataGrid Name="Table"
          Margin="10"
          LoadingRow="Table_LoadingRow"
          GridLinesVisibility="None"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Просто левая строчка-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Название элемента">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <ItemContainerTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                               Margin="5" />
                </ItemContainerTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!--Если в этом выпадающем списке будет "выключен", то второй станет не доступен-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Состояние датчика">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <ItemContainerTemplate>
                    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Condition}"
                              SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Включен" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Выключен" />
                    </ComboBox>
                </ItemContainerTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!--Второй выпадающий список-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Значение датчика">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <ItemContainerTemplate>
                    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Value}"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsActivated}">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Не доступно" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Открыто" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Закрыто" />
                    </ComboBox>
                </ItemContainerTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Код из файла MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Sensor> source = new List<Sensor> {
        new Sensor("Дверь в гостиную", 0, 1),
        new Sensor("Дверь в кухню", 1, 0),
        new Sensor("Входая дверь", 0, 1),
        new Sensor("Правое окно балкона", 1, 0),
        new Sensor("Левое окно балкона", 0, 1),
        new Sensor("Окно в гостинной", 0, 2)
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Table.ItemsSource = source;
    }

    void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Table.SelectedIndex != -1) {
            var condition = (byte)(sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex;
            source[Table.SelectedIndex].Condition = condition;
            Table.ItemsSource = null;
            Table.ItemsSource = source;
        }
    }

    private void Table_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var sensor = (Sensor)e.Row.DataContext;

        if (sensor.IsActivated) {
            e.Row.Background = Brushes.White;
        } else {
            e.Row.Background = Brushes.LightCoral;
        }
    }
}
```

[Здесь вы сможете скачать архив с проектом.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqkJo1qnSE_bxg-ya0AZyZz7gTXT)

Comment: У вас привязок как таковых нету, обычная работа с контроллами через код. Ну а по поводу вопроса - реализуйте `INotifyPropertyChanged`, который оповестит интерфейс об изменении свойства. Без него интерфейсу нет дела до того, что `IsActivated` в состоянии `true/false`. Ну а также я очень сильно советую вам с самого начала изучать MVVM паттерн.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я реализовал интерфейс в классе Sensor, и вызываю событие при каждом изменении свойств. Также я подправил саму связку, теперь она выглядит так: `Binding Path=IsActivated, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. Однако никакого эффекта это не дало.

Comment: Подождите, а что вы ожидаете в итоге? Я вот скачал проект, запускаю, ставлю в первом столбце "Выключен" и второй у меня становится неактивный. Вроде все как и должно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да, но это потому что я делаю это в методе ручками. А я бы хотел, чтобы оно работало даже если закомментировать код в методе ComboBox_SelectionChanged (MainWindow.xaml.cs). То есть данная задача решена, однако путь уж совсем не джедайский. А хотелось бы такие мелочи делать на одном xaml'e.

Comment: Я понял задачу, чуть позже дам развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так, давайте по порядку...

#### DataContext и ItemsSource

Вы задаете `this.Table.ItemsSource = source;`, хорошо, но что если у вас будет 10, 20, 30 контролов? У вас будет портянка кода с указанием `ItemsSource`? Также вы должны стремится к отделению View (своего XAML) от ViewModel (вашего кода) и в таком случае указание `ItemSource` полностью должно быть реализовано в View части приложения. Для установки `ItemSource` из XAML нам надо указать соответствующий `DataContext`. Давайте сделаем это:

- Вместо `this.Table.ItemsSource = source;` мы пишем `DataContext = this;`. `this` в данном случае, это `MainWindow`, но лучше создать отдельный класс (прим: `MainViewModel`) и его уже тут использовать.
- Коллекцию `source` переделываем в свойство и делаем публичным. - `public List<Sensor> source { get; set; } = ...`. Если вы будете добавлять/удалять объекты из коллекции, то стоит использовать `ObservableCollection<T>`.
- Убираем `Name="Table"` в XAML. Отвыкайте от работы с контролами через код, привязки ваше все!
- Задаем `DataGrid` нужный `ItemSource` - `ItemsSource="{Binding source}"`

Все, теперь у вас более менее правильная привязка с которой мы можем работать дальше.

#### INotifyPropertyChanged

Если мы привязали какое то свойство и меняем его через код, то для обновления View части нам необходимо реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

- Создадим класс, назовем его к примеру `BaseVM`.
- Наследуем его от `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
- Реализовываем самым простейшим способом:

  ```
  public class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
      {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
      }
  }
  ```
- Наследуем от созданного нами класса тот класс, где содержатся изменяемые свойства (`public sealed class Sensor : BaseVM`).
- В `Set` нужного свойства добавляем вызов INPC:

  ```
  private bool isActivated;
  public bool IsActivated
  {
      get => isActivated;
      set
      {
          isActivated = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
      }
  }
  ```

### Переносим логику

1. Вашу старую логику `public bool IsActivated => Condition == 0;` мы переносим в свойство `Condition` (p.s. `SelectedIndex` это `int`):

   ```
   private int condition;
   public int Condition {
       get => condition;
       set
       {
           condition = value;
           IsActivated = value == 0;
       }
   }
   ```

   Скорей всего не будет обновляться свойство. Дописываем в XAML `UpdateSourceTrigger` в привязке (`{Binding Path=Condition, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`).

   Все, теперь нам полностью не нужен `ComboBox_SelectionChanged`, отписываемся от него.
2. Цвет строки. Любые изменения в UI - это View часть, туда и стоит перенести. Реализуется это довольно легко, путем написания триггера. Внутри `DataGrid` пишем:

   ```
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActivated}" Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
               </DataTrigger>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActivated}" Value="False">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral"/>
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>
   ```

   Ну и убираем соответственно `Table_LoadingRow`.

Все, теперь ваше приложение имеет правильную привязку, без лишних событий и все по своим местам.

---

> реализовать данное приложение, как оно есть, по шаблону MVVM

Собственно почему бы и нет.
Для начала Вам стоит понимать, что такое MVVM подход и для чего он. Я особо рассказывать про его тонкости не буду, главное поймите то, что MVVM - это разделение логики приложения на 3 слоя, которые не связаны друг с другом почти не чем.

- Model - источник данных. В вашем случае это могут быть сенсоры, которые например берутся из базы или от куда либо еще.
- View - UI нашего приложения. В вашем случае это просто MainWindow.
- ViewModel - некий связующий слой, который работает с Model и предоставляет для View публичные свойства, к которым та в последующем привязывается.

Теперь давайте перепишем ваше приложение (имеем уже те правки, что выше).

**Основное:**

1. Создадим 3 папки, `Models`, `ViewModels`, `Views` (для удобства и лучшего понимания).
2. В `Views` перекидываем `MainWindows` целиком. После перекидывания изменяем в .cs и .xaml `namespace` (добавляем `.Views` (`Sample.Views..`).
3. В `ViewModels` переносим ранее созданный `BaseVM` (с заменой `namespace`).
4. В `ViewModels` создаем главный класс `MainViewModel`.
5. Теперь мы можем соединить все. Заходим в `App.xaml` и удаляем там `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`.
6. Заходим в `App.xaml.cs` и переписываем событие `OnStartup`, делая что то вроде этого:

   ```
   protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnStartup(e);
       new MainWindow() { DataContext = new MainViewModel() }.Show();
   }
   ```

   Так мы задали нужный нам `DataContext` и сами отображаем окно.
7. Удаляем из `MainWindow.xaml.cs` указанный нами ранее `DataContext`.
8. В местах где будет ругаться на namespace - дописываем нужный и запускаем проект. Должно успешно отобразится окно с дизайном, но без данных.

**Убираем лишнее из View слоя:**

1. Убираем все имена из XAML, они нам не к чему, их стоит использовать лишь в стилях, каких то триггерах или в чем то еще, где работа чисто на XAML.
2. Для удобства добавляем к `Window` (в XAML) следующее:

   ```
   xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Sample.ViewModels"
   d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}"
   ```

   Это позволит дизайнеру знать, какой `DataContext` сейчас установлен и он будет подсказывать нам об ошибках и предлагать свойства.
3. Убираем все `Path=` (вкусовщина), я считаю их лишним мусором.
4. Класс `Sensor`... Ну смотрите, это по сути источник данных и если сенсоры будут где то в базе или в другом месте, то стоит создать для них `Model`, где вы пропишете всю логику взаимодействия, пока же у вас это простой `List<>`, который спокойно можно уместить в VM слое. И по этому Переименовываем его в `SensorViewModel`, переносим в нужную папку, меняем `namespace`.
5. В `MainViewModel` переносим инициализацию наших сенсоров в созданное публичное свойство коллекции:

   ```
   class MainViewModel
   {
       public ObservableCollection<SensorViewModel> Sensors { get; }

       public MainViewModel()
       {
           Sensors = new ObservableCollection<SensorViewModel>()
           {
               new SensorViewModel("Дверь в гостиную", 0, 1),
               new SensorViewModel("Дверь в кухню", 1, 0),
               new SensorViewModel("Входная дверь", 0, 1),
               new SensorViewModel("Правое окно балкона", 1, 0),
               new SensorViewModel("Левое окно балкона", 0, 1),
               new SensorViewModel("Окно в гостиной", 0, 2)
           };
       }
   }
   ```
6. Привязываем `DataGrid` в XAML к этой коллекции (`ItemsSource="{Binding Sensors}"`).

Все, теперь ваше приложение разделено на слои. В XAML окна мы не связаны какими либо событиями с кодом, в `MainWindow.xaml.cs` у нас только инициализация контролов, а в `MainViewModel` у нас нету не намека на контролы из View слоя, ибо идет работа с данными напрямую. Вам же остается доделать все под себя, сделать Model слой (если нужен будет) и др. мелочи.

Comment: Не могли бы вы развить тему о предложении создать отдельный класс `MainViewModel`? Что это за класс? Он будет хранить в себе только наш `source`, либо в нем должно(может) быть что-то ещё? Какой класс он будет насследовать? Какие интерфейсы? P.S: очень трудно сдерживаться, но сообщество настоятельно просит обходиться без благодарственных комментариев.

Comment: @Kasper Это уже больше относится к MVVM подходу. Вся суть MVVM в том, что приложение делится на слои (Model <- ViewModel -> View). Стрелками я пометил то, как слои должны знать друг о друге и тут как видите View слой (интерфейс) не должен нечего знать о коде (VM/M слоях). А файл `MainWindow` (xaml.cs/.cs) это именно слой нашего UI и сейчас как видите он работает сам на себя, имеет логику, и нету VM слоя. Вот что бы его создать, стоит сделать класс в котором будет вся базовая логика, реализация других VM, работа с M слоями, и уже этот класс задавать в `DataContext` (и лучше это делать в App).

Comment: У вас очень хорошо получается разложить все по полочкам и я уже начал догонять что к чему. И для того, чтобы закрепить это все, не могли бы Вы реализовать данное приложение, как оно есть, по шаблону MVVM. Думаю это будет полезно также и для людей, который придут сюда позже.

Comment: Если с M и V все ещё понятно, то VM немного сбивает с толку. А живой пример решил бы эту проблему раз и на всегда.

Comment: @Kasper Обновил.