# обновление ListView из ViewModel без ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

У меня на форме есть ListView который сбиндин с коллекцией List находящейся во ViewModel

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Call_list, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Call_selected_index, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="ListView_Call_Selected">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Call" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Strike" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Strike}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Bid" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Bid}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Ask" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Ask}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Theoretical price" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TheoreticalPrice}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Last}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Volume total" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Volume}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Volume Bid" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ValumeBid}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Volume Ask" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=VolumeAsk}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="OI" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OI}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Delta" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Delta}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Vega" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Vega}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Gamma" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Gamma}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Thetta" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Thetta}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

ViewModel сделал следующим образом:

```
class OptionDeskManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public List<Desk_DataItems> Call_list { get; set; } = new List<Desk_DataItems>();


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new         
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

}
```

После перезаполнения коллекции Call_list - я вызываю `NotifyPropertyChange("Call_list");`

однако коллекция не обновляется. Я выбрал List вместо ObservableCollection так как мне иногда нужно просто обновлять данные не перезаписывая коллекцию,соответственно именно для этого и подписываю View на событие PropertyChanged.

Т.е. я единожды заполняю коллекцию, затем просто изменяю некоторые из ее элементов. к примеру `Call_list[0].Delta= 0.5; NotifyPropertyChange("Call_list");` как то так

Однако коллекция не обновляется. помогите разобраться где у меня недочет ?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` не чем не отличается от `List`, за исключением того, что она реализует `INotifyCollectionChanged`, который оповещает интерфейс об изменениях внутри коллекции (добавление/удаление), ну и пару мелочей у нее тоже другие. `выбрал List вместо ObservableCollection так как ... нужно просто обновлять данные не перезаписывая коллекцию` - для этого как раз и создана `ObservableCollection`.  `NotifyPropertyChange("Call_list");` - вам надо делать тогда, когда вы пишете `new List<..>();`, это оповещения интерфейса об изменении свойства (переинициализация, новое значение итд).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вы видимо не совсем меня поняли. Я единожды заполняю коллекцию, затем просто изменяю некоторые из ее элементов. к примеру `Call_list[0].Delta= 0.5; NotifyPropertyChange("Call_list");`
как то так.

Comment: Если у вас состав коллекции не изменяется, а изменяются только отдельные свойства у отдельных элементов коллекции, то вам нужно чтобы класс такого элемента реализовывал `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Смотрите. `Call_list[0].Delta= 0.5;`, разберем.. `Call_list` - это публичное свойство для привязки, некая коллекция (`List<Desk_DataItems>`). Вам не нужны тут не какие `NotifyPropertyChange` если вы не делаете пере-инициализацию уже существующего, привязанного объекта (то есть `=new List<..>();`. Если у вас коллекция статична (заполняется раз при инициализации (прим: `= new List<int>{1,2,3}`)) и вы не будете туда добавлять/удалять что то во время работы, то `List<>` вам будет в самый раз, иначе - используйте `ObservableCollection<>` (или пишите реализацию `INotifyCollectionChanged`).

Comment: Далее `.Delta = 0.5` - это у вас должно быть публичное свойство в `Desk_DataItems`. И тут принцип следующий: Если данное свойство меняет свое значение во время работы программы, то для оповещения UI вам обязательно надо сделать `INotifyPropertyChanged` внутри класса `Desk_DataItems` (или наследником от базового), и в `Set` обновляемого свойства вызвать ваш `NotifyPropertyChange()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ т.е. просто класс Desk_DataItems наследую от INotifyPropertyChanged, затем после изменения какого либо из элементов дергаю это событие. А в ListView нужно создовать столбцы следующим образом:
`<GridViewColumn Header="Call" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

я все верно понял ?

Comment: Не "просто наследую", а "наследую и реализую". "Не дергаю событие", а "Дергаю в `Set` нужного свойства". Почитайте про `INotifyPropertyChanged`, благо в интернете много полезной информации о его использовании. Либо хотя бы один из моих недавних [ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/957100/220553), где я реализовывал простенький INPC.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сейчас попробую, благодарю.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вроде получилось благодарю. Завтра еще протестирую (у меня источник обновлений из интернета днем работает только) если что то поспрашиваю еще.