# Передать из 1 viewmodel значения во вторую

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Использую WPF и паттерн MVVM. Хочу передать из одной viewmodel в другую значения(допустим текст).
Подключаю DataContext в разметке xaml в обеих viewmodel

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MWVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:W1VM/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Пробовал разные варианты, значение передается. И через перегрузку конструктора, и через доп методы класса, и через инициализатор.

```
 private RelayCommand _pageWindow1;
        public RelayCommand PageWindow1
        {
            get
            {
                return _pageWindow1 ??
                       (_pageWindow1 = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                       {
                           var vm = new W1VM("asdasdas")
                           {
                               Page1 = new Page1(),
                               //Text =  "Hello"
                           };
                           SlowOpacoty(vm.Page1);
                           //vm.Send();
                       }));
            }
        }
```

Но когда я нажимаю на кнопку во второй viewmodel, в переменной text почему-то всегда оказывается NULL.

```
    private RelayCommand _tCommand;
    public RelayCommand TCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _tCommand ??
                   (_tCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show(text);
                   }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Подключаю DataContext в разметке xaml` - зря, ой как зря... По поводу вопроса - `значение передается` .. `Но когда я нажимаю на кнопку ..в переменной text .. всегда оказывается NULL`, как такое может быть, если оно передается? Где тогда теряете, на каком этапе? P.S. `Page1` - я надеюсь вы не `Frame` используете?..

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Может я чего-то не понимаю, но ведь так зато вижу все команды и свойства во ViewModel. А подключая DataContext у окна, да и вообще обращаясь к нему вроде как нарушает MVVM. Да в этом примере был использован Frame, но вообще интересует Window. 
А чем так плох Frame?
И почему плохо подключать DataContext в XAML?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну из за того что DataContext объявлен в XAML, должен быть пустой конструктор у VM. И я пытаюсь передать через открытые свойства класса(public string text {get;set;}. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку и открывается Frame, передается значение. И когда я в новом Frame жму на кнопку, в переменной text NULL, да и в Page то же. Вот это и странно...

Comment: `DataContext` - я цитату хорошего человека вам покажу (VladD): 1. С точки зрения идеологии MVVM, View не может управлять VM. А когда View создаёт себе VM, она, очевидно, им управляет. 2. С практической точки зрения, если у нас есть несколько VM, и мы хотим их «связать», то нам недостаточно использовать конструкторы наших VM по умолчанию. Например, одна из VM может хотеть ссылку на другую. Если мы ограничиваемся созданием VM в XAML, мы получаем обязательное использование конструктора по умолчанию, и обязательно новую VM у каждого экземпляра контрола/окна. Это очень часто не то, чего мы хотим.

Comment: `Frame` - Тут дело в том, что он довольно плохо взаимодействует с MVVM подходом, у него есть много своих недостатков, ну и ко всему прочему он как по мне лишний. Хотите другое содержимое с MVVM подходом, используйте например [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553) подход. И вот если вы все это переделаете (DataContext и Frame), то у вас не составит труда передать данные из VM в VM, ибо это делается простым конструктором..

Comment: Что касательно вашей проблемы, то по сути нечего странного. Вы инициализируете `var vm = new W1VM("asdasdas") { Page1 = new Page1() };`, то есть инициализируете отдельно VM, которая не как не связана с `Page`, да в ней есть Page, но не в Page есть VM. А при `new Page1()` у вас создается другая VM, ибо вы ее задали в XAML. Вот и подумайте, где у вас переданное вами значение...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, это действительно так. Погуглив более подробно, нашел статью [ссылка](http://paulstovell.com/blog/mvvm-instantiation-approaches) Когда я в разметке подключаю DataContext 2ой VM и вызываю новое окно, оно тупо перетирает значения. Я не думал, что он реализует новый экземпляр класса ('new VM2()'). Я думал он получает ссылку на созданный что-то типо, 'DataContext = VM2', но к сожалению это не так)

Comment: Я советую вам задавать DataContect в App классе, например как я писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/957100/220553) (внизу, где `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)`). Там вы также можете найти решение для `зато вижу все команды и свойства во ViewModel` (пункт 2 в "Убираем лишнее").